# Angular UI Bootstrap typeahead does not extend past parent div border like a normal select dropdown

Tags: select, popup, angular-ui-bootstrap, typeahead, slimscroll

I'm using the [Angular UI Bootstrap typeahead](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) to display a customized list of suggestions as the user types into a text input form control. This form control exists inside a div using jQuery slimScroll in order to maintain a constant div size despite the size of its contents fluctuating. I really hoped the typeahead would display over everything like a regular html select dropdown, but unfortunately it does not, as can be seen in this [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/Ew6FCEiVesgqofREx4Q3/). I've tried futzing around with the z-index and adjusting the position and display properties; all fruitless endeavors.

Does anybody know how to get the typeahead popup to display over its parent border? If not, is there a way I could coerce the select tag to display HTML content so I can include glyphicons, emphasized text, etc. in the list of suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just set typeahead-append-to-body="true" on the typeahead control and it worked. Not sure exactly why, but it's certainly a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the slim scroll  - you are inside a div with relative position and overflow hidden (think of it as an iFrame). There is a small workaround...
You could, essentially set the position of the generated UL (.dropdown-menu) to *fixed*, set a height for it, then set an overflow:scroll... 
It would work in some scenarios where the input field has a fixed position... otherwise you'd need to control where the input is and adjust the position of the auto-complete to follow, and a whole other bunch of nasty scripts.

Without looking at your application, I cannot understand why your have this particular architecture, but I can say that there must be cleaner options for handling autocomplete outside of slimscroll.